# Interconnection between 2 computers in different networks

Tags: networking, kvm-switch

What I want is to connect 2 computers (work and personal) primary for using a software KVM (Input Director or Synergy). Transferring files between them would be a plus.

The main issue is that the work computer is in a secured enterprise network, and my personal computer is using a 3G+ modem for Internet access. On the work computer I do not have Internet access (only local network).

I want to somehow connect them without to mess up either networks. I want my personal computer to not be seen in the work network. Is it possible?

Suggestions:
- use a simple UTP cable to connect the 2 computers with each other. Can they each be in both 2 networks without issues?
- use some kind of usb cable, if exists

Comment: I assume your work computer is connected to its network with an ethernet cable. Do you have either a second ethernet or a wireless interface on that computer?

Comment: Yes, it is an ethernet cable. I can add an usb wireless interface (stick).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both computers have a spare Ethernet port, just connect them directly (a cross-over cable may or may not be necessary, depending on how old are the network cards), and configure IP addresses in the same subnet (separately from your existing networks). All relatively modern operating systems`*` can work with multiple networks.

---

`*` Including even Windows 95 and OS/2 Warp 4.

Comment: Can I use an ad-hoc wireless network - using the build-in wifi on laptop and an added usb wifi stick on work computer? Will my laptop be invisible from work network?

Comment: @cripox: Depends on what you mean by "visibility" (reachable through TCP/IP, seen by NetBIOS, etc). Most of the time though, the two networks (work LAN and your mini-network) should stay completely separate unless you manually bridge them.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a spare LAN port (which is the best solution as proposed by grawity), then you can insert a router (or a smart switch) to which they are both directly connected. The work PC should be connected to the this router first, then to the company wall jack or whatnot.

You can then pick a subnet that is not in the work domain - use something relatively uncommon, like 192.168.155.xxx. Then you can configure a virtual network connection on the enterprise PC (you do have full Admin, correct?), and the router will be configure to 'route' items on that subnet to your other PC rather than the company WAN / LAN.

It's a more complicated answer, and so I won't go into the specifics unless the other options don't pan out. Honestly if you don't have a second port on the company desktop, I'd buy a USB RJ-45 adapter which are pretty cheap and use that rather than the method I am describing.

I'm just throwing this idea out there as I don't know your level of competence with networking, and this approach may be worthwhile for you (it allows you to add all kinds of things to your local LAN without visibility to the company WAN - your own printer, NAS, etc, without having to configure those with much thought.

Plus I'm new to the site, and figured I'd get slammed with some negative points for confusing people. :)